# Exclude posts by ID in a custom query built with ACF Gutenberg blocks

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, acfpro

I have a ACF Gutenberg block with several options

- Display latest posts, lets say 5
- Display selected posts, is a list of posts from which I can select which to show.

If I add this block several times on a page, with the option to select the posts which I want, I don't want the posts from this block to be shown also in the block with the latest posts.

How can I make the query for the block with the related posts to exclude the posts from all other blocks ?

I tried `parse_blocks( $post->post_content )` but it display's a big object from which my block is maybe at the 10'th indentation.

I tried to store the post->ID of the posts in the option database with the page-id as key, but the last block will overwrite the stored values.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I manage eventually to do it with parse_blocks method, just be careful to don't add the blocks inside a column or a group, cause it will mess up your page object.